# FullCalendar Shrink rows with no events

Tags: fullcalendar

I am trying to replace an old calendar. One of the features of my old calendar was if no events exist in a row then the row shows up really small. This keeps the overall height of the calendar down.

Where as fullcalendar's version is much larger regardless of if events exist or not.

If a given week has an event then that row will go to normal size.

Is there a way I can accomplish this with fullcalendar to avoid fullcalendar using so much space when there are no events?

Thanks to John 4d5 my calendar went from this:

[image: Large Calendar]

To This:

[image: Small Calendar]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I guess I didn't finish my question. The question is is there a way to do this in fullcalendar. I had pictures to illustrate this however I didn't have enough points on stackoverflow to post them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the function `setMinHeight` within FullCalendar's lib. Here is the function:

```
function setMinHeight(element, height) {
    height = (typeof height == 'number' ? height + 'px' : height);
    element.each(function(i, _element) {
        _element.style.cssText += ';min-height:' + height + ';_height:' + height;
    });
}
```

Change the **fourth line** to this:

```
_element.style.cssText += ';min-height:' + 0 + ';_height:' + height;
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what i was looking for. Can't believe more people haven't asked for this.

Comment: Is this possible with todays fullcalendar? I cant find that function in the library.